# Can PHP maintain position in window on refresh? If not, best method?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have a div with CSS style `overflow: scroll;`.  It is long list that scrolls down far, but the div is only 300px in height.  If I scroll down, and click on an item, the content fills the right side of the window (the list is on the left side).  However, the list, naturally bumps up to the top back to refresh (need to refresh to grab content from a `MySQL` database).

I know, Ideally, using come kind of combo of JavaScript, jQuery or AJAX may work best -- but I only use JS and jQuery on a small level, and AJAX none at all.  I am much more familiar with PHP.

**Edit:**  Since PHP can not do this, what is the best way to implement and how?

**Edit2:**  Here is my link I click:

```
<a href="items.php?id=<?php echo $cat_id; ?>&amp;item=<?php echo urlencode($row['item']); ?>"><?php echo $row['item']; ?></a>
```

Comment: Wrong tool. PHP is blind to the client's scroll-position. It isn't very hard with JS.

Comment: PHP is a server side application. It does not interact with your window. You need jQuery for this.

Comment: didn't know if overflow has that value

Comment: @user543732  Typo and fixed.

Comment: @Cthulhu I revised the question, can you assist with the JS method if it isn't very hard?

Comment: @KickingLettuce if you dont have a clue about the difference between php and js i suggest you study before going making questions. no offense, its cuz ppl are troll here and are gonna downvote you.

Comment: @Ark I understand the difference between server-side and client-side scripting.  Didn't know if there was a PHP hack or not.  I assumed most likely not, but if there was, I'm sure the fine SO posters would have an answer.

Comment: -1 for multiple question.  Take look over google for 'infinite Scrolling' .. -->  http://designbeep.com/2011/08/12/12-jquery-infinite-scrollingscroll-read-plugins-for-content-navigation/

Comment: @Ark - I somewhat agree, but text slang tends to be deprecated here also `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

In your html:

```
<div class='item_in_list'><a href='javascript:item_click(<?php echo $id;?>)'>Item 1</a></div>
```

then the javascript:

```
function item_click(id)
{
$.ajax({
 type:'get',
 data:{item_id:id},
 url:'yourphppage.php',
 dataType:'html',
 success:function(response){
  $('#page_body').html(response);
  return false;
 }
});
}
```

Comment: This sounds like good method.  I am not familiar with AJAX at all but it looks like jQuery.  I see what is going on here but trying to relate that to what I have done.  I added the link I click on above, can you apply that to what you did in the `HTML`?

Comment: the html calls the javascript function with the id of the item passed as an argument

Comment: by `id`, is this the same `id` in the MySQL table for the data of the list I am using? If so, can I just use any unique data from that table?

Comment: yes. i am assuming you are retrieving a record based upon the primary key

Comment: I think I am making progress here: My link would actually be, `href="javascript:item_click(<?php echo $cat_id; ?>, <?php echo urlencode($row['item']); ?>)"` and in the `function item_click(cat_id, item) `,  I have ` data:{cat_id:cat_id; item: item },`  IF this is correct, I just need to figure out the success/response.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to access your element by ID after having refreshed the page ?

Basically adding '#elementClickedId' at your url ?

Something like : 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with this (assumed jQuery is loaded):

```
<script>

$( '.list a' ).click( function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();

    alert( 'Loading...' );

    $( '#resultboxontheright' ).load( 'foo.php?id=' + $( this ).attr( 'data-foo' ), function() {

        alert( 'Done!' );

    } );

} );

</script>


<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="foo.php?id=bar" data-foo="bar">Foobar</a></li>
    <li><a href="foo.php?id=foo" data-foo="foo">Foofoo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="resultboxontheright"></div>
```

and the foo.php:

```
<?php

echo '<h4>' . $_GET['id'] . '</h4>';
```

Comment: thanks... going to try this out